# SQL table foreign keys working differently - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server, I have a small group of tables I'm working on. Two of the tables have similar functionality - a foreign key to the primary key in the same table.

I'm an SQL novice. From what I understand, the two tables should enforce the same rules - but they don't. Have I made a schoolboy error, or are there situations where they could work differently?

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Page] 
(
    [Id]        SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [IsActive]  BIT NOT NULL     
        CONSTRAINT [DF_Page_IsActive] DEFAULT ((0)),
    [IsDeleted] BIT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [DF_Page_IsDeleted] DEFAULT ((0)),
    [RouteId]   SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [ParentId]  SMALLINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Page] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Page_RouteId_Route_Id] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([RouteId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Route] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Page_ParentId_Page_Id] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Page] ([Id])
);
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Topic]  
(
    [Id]       SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
    [Name]     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] SMALLINT    NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Topic] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_Topic_Name] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Name] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Topic_ParentId_Topic_Id] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Topic] ([Id])
);
```

Each of the above tables has a column `ParentId` which references the main `Id` with a FK constraint.

- Table 1 works as I expected it would (that does not mean it's correct in that `ParentId` must match an entry in the `Id` column - no exceptions!
- Table 2 works slightly differently. Suppose `Id` contained the Id's 1 to 10. Id 11 upwards isn't allowed, but weirdly '0' is accepted. Zero is not accepted on table 1.

The only think I can think of that differentiates them is that Table 1 Id is linked to from other tables. I can't see why it would make a difference though.

Any ideas as to why I get this behaviour?

Comment: *"but weirdly '0' is accepted"* then there is a row where it has the value `0` for `Id`.

Comment: could you share the sql statements you have run that resulted in the unusual output

Comment: I cannot reproduce: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bcb999c542ab4b97601aebb51853c48d)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio, so I just type in a few examples rather than through an INSERT. I've since amended them to valid Id's (accepted), invalid Id's (rejected), and back to 0 (accepted).

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: @Larnu As I said, I've been changing the existing data without being challenged. However after deleting the existing data and recreating it, I was challenged, so it looks like it wasn't re-evaluating the data on change in the first instance. It is now. It could be that the  constraint was created after data.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE Topic CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL` the constraint was set to `NOCHECK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that on your Table 1 the constraint is "with check add constraint", explicity say that checks the values when you try to insert data, and in the table2 it's without check constraint.

Review your tables, and verify that.
On Designer you can see on foreign key relationship "Check existing data on create", review if set to yes.

Alternatively, you can do this in T-SQL

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Topic CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```

Comment: I'm looking at VS Designer but I can't see "check existing data on create". Also checked Management Studio

Comment: On SQL Management studio right click on your table and select "design", then on toolbar "table designer" select "relationship" icon, and select the foreign key. Option 2 is right click on your table and select "Script table as... Create to new window" and paste here the script to review.